# Facebook mutual "likes" not showing

Tags: facebook, fbml

I just build a Facebook fan page and the mutual likes are no longer showing up. I've tried googling around a solution but can't seem to find the proper way to ask this. Before I uploaded my custom polls and all, mutual likes were showing up, but now only the regular likes are showing. Does anyone know the proper FBML or code required to get it to show up?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this might have something to do with the age of the page.  Sometimes it could take up to 7 days for this to appear correctly.  At least that is what I think

Comment: I want to add some credence to this answer.  This is true even for Test Users.  Pretty annoying, especially if you don't know!